# What is graphical addition?

Tags: calculus

"Use the graphs of f and g and the method of graphical addition to sketch the graph of $f + g$".

$f(x) = x, g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Are you sure of $g''$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That's an immortal comment.  Congratulations!

Comment: @MichaelHoppe. Good joke ! I did not see the opening $"$ (I am almost blind). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Well, I know about your handicap, please don't feel offended by my comment and if you do so I apologize. But anyways, your comment stated as is is unbeatable.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe. Please don't worry. I did feel offended at all. I also find my comment worth to the museum of mathematics. Cheers and thanks for the joke !

Comment: @MichaelHoppe. Another bug ! I did **not** feel offended at all !! I just forgot to type the $not$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphical addition means $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ for all domain elements.

So you need to graph $(f+g)(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: So $(f + g)(x)$ is nothing but $x + \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Hah, just figured it out a moment before you posted. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You plot each function on the same pair of axes.  Then for each $x$ value of interest, you plot $(f+g)(x)$ by measuring $g(x)$ above the $f(x)$ line.  It results in the same thing as making a table of values of $(f+g)(x)$ and plotting them.  I believe "graphical addition" refers to the process of adding the functions on the graph paper.